# How do I connect SQL Server to Redis in a C#/.NET application?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, redis

I have a web site for which I would like to use Redis as the default caching mechanism to load certain pages of our site. I've set up a local instance of Redis and want to access my SQL Server database, but I'm not quite sure how to have the files of the particular pages loaded via Redis, and how to connect Redis to SQL Server. I've searched extensively on Google, and really only found how to set up Redis on a C#/.NET application (which I've done succesfully), but not really how to connect it to SQL Server and query the database. I hope this wasn't too broad, so let me know if you need more information and thank you for your help!

Comment: I'm using SSMS to access databases stored in SQL Server. Does that help?

Comment: And unfortunately the question pretty much is too broad.

Comment: Gotcha, thanks for the correction, and I also want to let all know in case they don't use SSMS.

Comment: Understood. Is there anything that would help narrow it down?

Comment: I saw that, and she's using Node, which to be honest, I've only used by itself and not in conjunction with C#. Is that still manageable without using Node?

Comment: Sorry @DaleK, I didn't mention I'm using .NET. Yes, I would assume anything can be done with either, I'm rather looking specifically how to query from .NET. Creating routes in Node I'm comfortable with, but I'm quite new to .NET/C# and was wondering if there was a best-practice for querying SQL Server from said framework.

Comment: Yes, there are many good resources for that, I'm just missing the piece of throwing Redis in there.

Comment: I'm not sure why, but reading your last answer made sense in a way that it should have waaay before. If you want to add that as an answer, I'll upvote it, and thank you for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Choose an appropriate point in your application life cycle style to load your data for caching.
2. Write C# code to access your SQL Server and pull the data you wish to cache.
3. Use the Redis API to store this data in Redis.
4. Make all access to this data use the Redis API.
5. Handle a cache miss i.e. when the expected data isn't present.
6. Implement a cache refresh mechanism to ensure data is updated when required.

Comment: With the steps to boot? You're the man, thank you!